# Store arraylist of custom class in file which is not serializable

Tags: android, caching

Hi I want to store data in file but my problem is that class which I want to store is non editable & is not serialized, How can I store it?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example serializing it yourself to json or xml? Can be easily done with Gson or Jackson

Comment: Yes tried with gson but while writing it to file it throws exception

Comment: Can you a) share the Exception thrown, and b) share the code of the non editable and non serializable class?

Answer (score 0):

You can either extend the class and implement Serializable or in case that isn't possible you can serialize the parameters and recreate the objects when loading them back.

Comment: My Structure is like this:
Class A implements Serializable
{
 private Collection<B> attachments;
}
Here B is not serilalizable & both are non editable